# I want to pass multiple arguments to python script from bash script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

I have a python script that takes some inputs as arguments. I bash script I want to provide those inputs. here is the input syntax :

```sh
usage: $0 <virtualenv-dir>
          <cairo-dir>
          <file-path>
          [--server <es-server>]
          [--port <es-port>]
          [--fields <columns to be uploaded. Comma separated list of columns]
          [--filter <ES filter to use>]
          [--from-time <start time>]
          [--to-time <end time>]
          [--timestamp-field <name-of-timestamp-column>]
          <index-name> 
          <recipients-separated-by-comma>
          <output-file-name>
```

I want to learn how to assign these inputs to variable in a bash script and pass the variables to python script.

I tried these :

```
VIRTUAL_ENV=$1
CAIRO=$2
PYTHON_FILE_SCRIPT=$3
INDEX=$4
MAIL_LIST=$5
FILE_OUTPUT=$6
shift
shift

# Activate virtual environment
source $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate

# Set PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$UBUNTU

cd $UBUNTU

# a cronjob to collect the data from the device
python $3 $4 $5 $6
```

Comment: As long as there are no spaces in variables this should be okay (though that is not to be relied upon, you should always quote variable use in bash scripts: `VIRTUAL_ENV="$1"`, `cd "$UBUNTU"`, `python "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6"`...). When you "tried these", what problem did you encounter?

Comment: @Amadan whatever I give input for <recipients-separated-by-comma> give ing me error python: can't open file 'abc@gmail.com': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Are you trying to parse your input for those optional fields? You seem to make no attempt to do that here.

Comment: @AdamSmith How to do that?

Comment: @SmrutiSahoo I bet `abc@gmail.com` is the second address in the list. Since you don't quote the input, there's no way of knowing that `a@b.c, d@e.f outputfile.txt` is supposed to be two email addresses separated by a comma or one email address (ending in a comma) followed by an outputfile named `d@e.f`.

Answer (score 1):

The python command seems incorrect: you already called shift, so `$3`, which is the python script, is now `$1`.

Replace the last line with

```sh
python "$PYTHON_FILE_SCRIPT" "$INDEX" "$MAIL_LIST" "$FILE_OUTPUT"
```

and you should be just fine.

If you want to perform options parsing, I would suggest you use a `while` loop and shift arguments while parsing. You can use a `case` to match options easily. Example:

```sh
VIRTUAL_ENV="$1"
CAIRO="$2"
PYTHON_FILE_SCRIPT="$3"

while true; do
    case "$1" in
    --server)
        SERVER="$2"
        shift 2
        ;;
    --port)
        PORT="$2"
        shift 2
        ;;
# add other cases
    *)
        break
        ;;
    esac
dome

INDEX=$4
MAIL_LIST=$5
FILE_OUTPUT=$6

# then do what you need to do
```